# SQL: Unrolling a set

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have a set in SQL like this:

```
    Product | Quantity
       A         1
       B         2
```

I want (in a single SELECT statement) to transform that to:

```
    Product 
       A    
       B    
       B
```

Can anyone point me towards (T-SQL preferably), a trick on how to do this?

Comment: It's not unpivoting; you're wanting to recreate rows based on summarized data...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an intermediary numbers table, or a table-valued function (if that option is available to you) which will produce numbers.

Assuming you had a Numbers table, which is populated like so:

```
    Number
    ------
         1
         2
       ...
    100000
```

(or as large as you need it to be, and there are [efficient mechanisms for generating a numbers table of large size](http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/tblnumbers.aspx))

You would then issue the following query:

```
select
    p.Product
from
    Products as p
        inner join Numbers as n on n.Number <= p.Quantity
```

This would produce the result you want.

A numbers table is incredibly helpful in SQL, and [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.solidq.com/insidetsql/) goes into it and other great querying techniques in his books (listed on his website).  I highly recommend them.

Comment: @Carl Manaster: Thank you, but I can't take the credit, I learned it from Itzik Ben-Gan's books, and credited him appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProductName, Quantity from Product
```

ProductName Quantity

---

A           1

B           2

C           4

Here is one select, as you wish (sql server 2005):

```
with result (ProductName, Q)
as
(
    select ProductName, 1 from Product where Quantity > 0
    union all
    select p1.ProductName, result.q + 1 from Product p1
    inner join result on result.ProductName = p1.ProductName
    where result.q < p1.Quantity 
)
select p2.ProductName from Product p2
    inner join result on result.ProductName = p2.ProductName
order by 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

### ProductName

A
B
B
C
C
C
C

Comment: Just a couple of issues: (1) to avoid listing products with quantity 0, add condition to the anchor select, and (2) it will not work if quantity is greater than 100 because that is the default recursion limit so need to add "option (maxrecursion 0)" at the end.

Comment: Sure, but the anchor select needs to have an actual where clause to exclude products with quantity zero instead of starting from 0: select ProductName, 1 from Product where Quantity > 0

Answer (score -1):

Try CURSOR??

```
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
DECLARE @Product varchar(50)

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Product FROM dbo._YourTable

OPEN @Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Product 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @Count int
SET @Count = 0

DECLARE @Quantity int
SET @Quantity = SELECT Quantity FROM dbo._YourTable WHERE Product = @Product

WHILE @Count < @Quantity
BEGIN

SELECT @Product as Product
@Count = @Count + 1

END

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Product
END

DEALLOCATE @Cursor
```

Comment: No, that would be the easy procedural hack way. I wanted to this using sets (like I said in my question).